# Fitted regression line parameters in python

Tags: python, plot, linear-regression, statsmodels

How can I get the intercept and the slope of the fitted regression line in `qqplot`? Here's a small working example, where I want the parameters of the red regression line:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.normal(0, 4, 100)
sm.qqplot(a, stats.norm(loc=5, scale=1), line="r")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the x,y coordinates of the line and use numpy polyfit to get your slope and intercept.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.normal(0, 4, 100)
fig = sm.qqplot(a, stats.norm(loc=5, scale=1), line="r")

line = fig.gca().lines[-1]

slope, intercept =  np.polyfit(line.get_xdata(),line.get_ydata(),1)

print(slope, intercept)
```

Output

```
4.027047644266026 -20.55190163670639
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the returned figure to grab the relevant axes and line and calculate slope and intercept from the xydata.  For reference, fig.axes[0].lines[0] is the data, lines[1] is the fit.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.normal(0, 4, 100)
fig = sm.qqplot(a, stats.norm(loc=5, scale=1), line="r")


# Grab line data from figure
xydata = fig.axes[0].lines[1].get_xydata()
diff = (xydata - np.roll(xydata, 1, axis = 0))[1:]
slopes = diff[:, 1]/diff[:, 0]
slope = slopes.mean()

y_ints = xydata[:, 1] - slope*xydata[:, 0]
y_int = y_ints.mean()

# Re-plot line for visual confirmation
plt.plot(xydata[:, 0], xydata[:, 0]*slope + y_int, 'k--')
```